# How to use a WatchKit Services Certificate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit, watchos-2

Recently, Apple has introduced "WatchKit Services Certificate" to its development portal.  From the description below, it appears to allow users to leverage push notifications to update Watch Complications directly.  But, the CLKComplicationDataSource protocol contains no information how how to implement this.  Does anyone have any further information on this?

From Apple's Developer site:
"Establish connectivity between your notification server, the Apple Push Notification service sandbox, and production environment to update ClockKit complication data. When utilizing HTTP/2, the same certificate can be used to deliver app notifications, update ClockKit complication data, and alert background VoIP apps of incoming activity. A separate certificate is required for each app you distribute."

No one knows on the Apple forums:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19594

CLKComplicationDataSource Protocol Reference
https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/ClockKit/Reference/CLKComplicationDataSource_protocol/

More documentation, but no implementing details:
http://images.apple.com/certificateauthority/pdf/Apple_WWDR_CPS_v1.13.pdf

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the WWDC 2015 video called [Introducing Watch Connectivity](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-713/). Take a look at about minute 50. This describes how you go about registering your complication for push notifications using PushKit. It doesn't go into detail about using a WatchKit Services Certificate, so I would try to use the normal iOS Push Notification certificate to actually send the notifications first, and if that doesn't work try sending the same message using the WatchKit Services Certificate instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @lehn0058.  I appreciate it.  I'm not going to mark this as an answer just yet because I'm hoping someone out there might have a little more.  Thanks, again!